# Install SmoothTasks in Kubuntu / general tarball installation help

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, 11.10

I'm trying to install [SmoothTasks](https://store.kde.org/p/999204/) - it's a KDE taskbar resembling Windows 7. I can't figure how to install it. I know it's an easy question for someone who knows, but it would help me very much to finally understand tarball installation and how to finally pull one through.

Answer (score 2):

**Repositories**

Many applications are in the official repositories. SmoothTasks is a plasma widget: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plasma-widget-smooth-tasks&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all

**PPA**

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

Searching the plasma-widget-smooth-tasks: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=plasma-widget-smooth-tasks

**Building from the sources**

A start point: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

**Generic plasmoid build**

From a plasmoid README file:

> cd /where/your/applet/is/decompressed
>
> mkdir build
>
> cd build
>
> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='kde4-config --prefix' ..
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

**Different KDE versions. KDE 4.7 vs KDE 4.8**

http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56838-SOLVED-When-plasma-widget-smooth-tasks-will-be-available

**Build depencies**

**Q:**

> I tried installing on KDE 4.7, then on KDE 4.8. Both give me missing
>   dependency reports (if you need to see them I'll post them)

**A:**

The base package for the building:

- build-essential

> If you have this package installed, you only need to install whatever
>   a package specifies as its build-time dependencies to build the 
>   package.

From the official Ubuntu package:  plasma-widget-smooth-tasks/debian/control; Build-Depends:

- gettext
- kde-workspace-dev
- libx11-dev
- cmake

Comment: I tried installing on KDE 4.7, then on KDE 4.8. Both give me missing dependency reports (if you need to see them I'll post them) every time I try installing, and I've yet to find a solution to this. Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: I'd really appreciate some help, if possible.